# How to configure multiple data sources in apache nifi

Tags: apache-nifi

I need to connect to different data sources to execute the sql queries from that data sources based on my datasource name,let say if my datasourceis A, then i have to connect A database by passing the valid credentials of A and get execute the table and get the data. If my datasource B, then i need to connect with B by passing valid credentials of B database and get the table execution and get the results. I may have any number of data sources. Is it possible to do this with DBCPConnectionPoolLookup, If so could anyone help me how should i configure DBCPConnectionPoolLookup and how should i configure Database Connection Pooling Service dynamically in my executesqlrecord processor of nifi.

Comment: How do you "pass the valid credentials"? Do you know them ahead of time? If so, set up the separate DBCPConnectionPool instances, then name them in DBCPConnectionPoolLookup and set the attribute `database.name` before the processor where you use the Lookup controller service.